# Include shapely 'Polygon' in a manim scene?

Tags: geopandas, shapely, manim

**Problem Statement**
I am creating a manim scene which requires manipulation of a geographical map; I usually handle map data using geopandas, which makes use of shapely polygons for storing boundary info. However, manim requires polygon data to be in an array of vertices (not a shapely polygon).

I am wondering if there an efficient way of using shapely polygons in manim?

**What I have tried**

I used the following to obtain an array of vertices:

```
c = shapely.get_coordinates(divisions.geometry, include_z=True)
c[np.isnan(c)] = 0
```

With output:

```
[[725489.329 672935.84       0.   ]
 [725473.525 672957.407      0.   ]
 [725450.981 672957.861      0.   ]
 ...
 [725492.777 672959.309      0.   ]
 [725501.73  672944.054      0.   ]
 [725489.329 672935.84       0.   ]]
```

Now, the problem is that when I attempt to display the polygon as follows:

```
%%manim -qm -v WARNING Etymology
class Etymology(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        self.camera.background_color = BLACK
        polygon = Polygon(*c)
        self.play(Create(polygon))
```

It simply displays a black screen. I have attempted to move the polygon to the origin as I orginally thought it was off screen; however, this did not work. This leads me to believe that the polygon is not being displayed at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With coordinate like `725489.329, 672935.84, 0.` your polygon is not just off-screen, it's far outside the boundaries of the standard Manim scene which stretches from `-7 <= x <= +7` and `-4 <= y <= +4`

The following code should work just fine:

```
%%manim -qm Etymology

c= [[725489.329, 672935.84,       0.   ],
 [725473.525, 672957.407,      0.   ],
 [725450.981, 672957.861,      0.   ],
 [725492.777, 672959.309,      0.   ],
 [725501.73,  672944.054,      0.   ],
 [725489.329, 672935.84,       0.   ]]

class Etymology(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        self.camera.background_color = BLACK
        polygon = Polygon(*c).scale_to_fit_width(10).move_to(ORIGIN)
        self.play(Create(polygon))
```

[image]